# how to run 2 python files in one go?

Tags: python

I have 2 python files `main.py` and  `test.py` when I run `main.py` I want to run `test.py` and some point of time in new terminal because if I run in same terminal `main.py` got crashed and closed and program fails.

Any ideas how can I do this.

Comment: it's very unclear what you want. where do "terminals" come into play here? why does crashing close a terminal? That makes no sense, either.

Answer (score 0):

Main.py must call other files to run them

Comment: I cannot do that it makes main.py file slow and also sometimes crash the program

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for sure without reading the code whether it will work, but here's the steps to run two pieces of code simultaneously:

1. Open File Explorer, and navigate to where you have saved the files.
2. Write `cmd` in the address bar of the file explorer.
3. When the prompt opens up, write the python command that you use to run the first file: `py <filename>.py` or `python <filename.py>` or `python3 <filename.py>`.
4. Repeat process 2 and 3, but this time, type the name of the second file.

Comment: please give detail answer

Comment: @unknownguyhere edited my answer to suit it.

Comment: Bro read question carefully I want to run test.py when some code runs successfully in main.py

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash you can do the following:

```
python3 demo.py && python3 program2.py
```

In that way if the first command is executed properly the following command will be executed.

If you don't have any depency in the way that the scripts have to be executed you can do also the following:

```
python3 demo.py; python3 program2.py
```

In this way second `program2.py` file will be executed even if the first command fails.